# How to predefine Apple Script constants or variables

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript

Is it possible to predefine constant or variable for an AppleScript in cocoa application?
in other words is the function "addConstantToAppleScript" (used in the following code) definable?

```
addConstantToAppleScript("myText", "Hello!");
char *src = "display dialog myText";
NSString *scriptSource = [NSString stringWithCString:src]; 
NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptSource];
NSDictionary *scriptError = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[appleScript executeAndReturnError:scriptError];
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prepend an `NSDictionary` of key/value pairs to the beginning of an `NSString` containing AppleScript you could use something like the following function.  Personally I would do this as a category on NSString but you have asked for a function.

```
NSString *addConstantsToAppleScript(NSString *script, NSDictionary *constants) {
    NSMutableString *constantsScript = [NSMutableString string];

    for(NSString *name in constants) {
        [constantsScript appendFormat:@"set %@ to \"%@\"\n", name, [constants objectForKey:name]];
    }   

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", constantsScript, script];
}
```

This function converts the key/value pairs to AppleScript statements of the form `set <key> to "<value>"`.  These statements are then added to the front of the supplied `script` string.  The resulting script string is then returned.

You would use the above function as follows:

```
// Create a dictionary with two entries:
//     myText = Hello\rWorld!
//     Foo    = Bar
NSDictionary *constants = [[NSDictionary alloc ] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hello\rWorld!", @"myText", @"Bar", @"Foo", nil];

// The AppleScript to have the constants prepended to   
NSString *script = @"tell application \"Finder\" to display dialog myText";

// Add the constants to the beginning of the script 
NSString *sourceScript = addConstantsToAppleScript(script, constants);

// sourceScript now equals
//     set Foo to "Bar"
//     set myText to "Hello\rWorld!"
//     tell application "Finder" to display dialog myText

NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:sourceScript];
```

Comment: because myText may contains special characters such as ' " \r \n , ... and I do not want to replace \r with \\r , ... also myText may too long.

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't be able to put special characters into the `variables` string.  Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "assign an object to myText later".

Comment: because myText may contains special characters such as ' " \r \n , ... and I do not want to replace \r with \\r , ... also myText may too long. (I edited and corrected my prev comment).

Comment: I think you're bigger issue is the error, "No user interaction allowed", that I get when I try to show a dialog using `NSAppleScript`.

Comment: I've updated my answer now that I've got it to actually display a dialog.

Comment: thank you, it works but I still interest to know if the function "addConstantToAppleScript" definable or no.

Comment: I've written an addConstantsToAppleScript function that will add an NSDictionary of key/value pairs to the beginning of an AppleScript string.